# How to implement IPC renderer to resize a window in electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I want to resize my electron window on button click. i have this code:-

In Main.html

```
<button id="btn">Resize</button>
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    let {ipcRenderer} = electron;
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ipcRenderer.send('resize');
    });
</script>
```

in main.js

```
let {ipcMain} = electron;
ipcMain.on('resize', function (event,args) {
win.setSize(400,800);
});
```

What should I write specifically in place of event inside the function. If i Just try to use this

```
ipcMain.on('resize', function () {
    win.setSize(400,800);
    });
```

It doesnt work

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Any error messages in your console or the console of the developer tools?

Comment: where is `win` defined? Is it accessible in the callback?

Comment: no there is no error message. It is defined in main.js where i define IPCmain.... It just does not catch the message. I am coding in react